# Nestjs: How to disable cache when dev?

Tags: node.js, typescript, redirect, caching, nestjs

I'm new in `Nestjs`. I have a issue when dev with `@Redirect()`.

Ex:

```
@Get('/hi')
@Redirect('https://nestjs.com',301);
hi() {
  return 'hi';
}
```

It is a `Get` in `Cats.controler.ts`.

When I go to `http://localhost:3000/cats/hi`, It's ok when redirect me to `nestjs.com`.

But when I change code, I remove `Redirect`:

```
@Get('/hi')
hi() {
  return 'hi';
}
```

It still redirect me to `nestjs.com`. That so bad.

Even when I stop app, then go to `http://localhost:3000/cats/hi`, I am redirected to `nestjs.com`.

I think that maybe have some cache or something make it can not run new code.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Hi there, the reason is you are using permanent 301 redirects, your browser remembers that and will always use the redirect, if you specify an address, to fix this you have to use res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store'); before sending the response to disable caching on browser side, you can also make it conditional by some env variable,